# POST method does the correct post and then rerenders the whole page

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, navigation, jinja2

I am using a post to get a parameter based on a radio button that a user selects and then submits and the correct operation happens but then below the page an entire new page comes up that the user is not logged into.  I am not quite sure what is happening but here is the applicable code and I am using HTML of course plus google appengine with python and jinja2.

HTML here:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="category" value="discussion">Discussion<br>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="adventures">Adventures<br>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="reviews">Reviews<br>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="badges">Badge Applications<br>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-medium btn-primary" value="Filter!">
</form>
```

python here:

```
def post(self):
    category = self.request.get('category')

    if category:
        user = users.get_current_user()
        logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        global visits

        category = self.request.get('category')                
        posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Post where category=:1 order by created desc limit 30", category)
        self.render("home.html", posts=posts, user=user, visits=visits, logout=logout)
```

my home.html doc:

```
        {% for post in posts %}
            {{post.render() | safe}}
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question i understand that user is not logged-in, in this case try the following:

```
def post(self):     
  category = self.request.get('category')      
  if category:         
    user = users.get_current_user()         
    if user:
      logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)         
      global visits          
      category = self.request.get('category')                         
      posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Post where category=:1 order by created desc limit 30", category)         
      self.render("home.html", posts=posts, user=user, visits=visits, logout=logout) 
    else:
      self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

Comment: well it shouldn't matter that the user is logged in.  and the page is rendering correctly initially but then below the correct rendering is the bad page where the user is not logged in.

Comment: I think the problem may be that it is sending all of the forms on the page, which doesn't make sense because I closed off all of my <form> tags.  Do input buttons without a specific input submit more than just the specific form that they are in?

Comment: so with your addition and the changing an else statement to an elif statement towards the bottom of the page I was able to fix it.  thanks!